# Read 'n' lines from file and assign each line to distinct variable

Tags: bash, while-loop

I generate a text file based on nodes in the cluster.

```
cat primary_nodes.txt
clusterNodea
clusterNodeb
..
....
clusterNoden
```

While I try to generate variable for each line, it gives me following output

```
while read PRIMARY_NODE$((i++)); do
echo $PRIMARY_NODE1
echo $PRIMARY_NODE2
done < primary_node.txt

clusterNodea
clusterNodea
clusterNodeb
```

What I want is:

1. It should return total no.of nodes
2. Each line should be assigned to PRIMARY_NODE1...n variable incrementally
3. Return all variable with its value.

Comment: As an aside -- All-caps variable names are [specified by POSIX-defined convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) for variables with meaning to the OS or shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of *dynamic* variable assignment using `declare` and *indirect expansion* as

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # The 'declare' syntax creates variables on the fly with the values
    # read from the file
    declare primaryNode$((i++))="$line"
done <file

count="$((i-1))"

# Now the variables are created; those can be individually accessed as  
# '$primaryNode1'..'$primaryNoden'; but to print it on a loop, use
# indirect expansion using ${!var} syntax  

for ((idx=1; idx<=count; idx++)); do
    temp=primaryNode$idx
    printf "PRIMARY NODE%s=%s\n" "$idx" "${!temp}" 
done
```

Comment: Bingo!...You are the expert. It works like a charm...

Comment: @CoolChap007: Happy you found it useful!

Answer (score 2):

#### The Right Thing: An Array

In bash 4:

```
readarray -t primary_node <primary_node.txt
```

Thereafter:

```
echo "${primary_node[0]}" # clusterNodea
echo "${primary_node[1]}" # clusterNodeb
```

Or to iterate over the values:

```
for node in "${primary_node[@]}"; do
  echo "Processing node $node"
done
```

---

#### The Wrong Thing: Distinct Variables

```
i=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf -v "primary_node$((i++))" '%s' "$line"
done <primary_node.txt

echo "$primary_node1"
```

---

#### References

- [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) - "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"
- [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) - "How can I use array variables?"
- [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) - "How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?"

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are your friend here:

```
readarray -t MYARRAY <primary_nodes.txt
$ echo ${MYARRAY[0]}
clusterNodea
$ echo ${MYARRAY[1]}
clusterNodeb
```

Note that it's possible to also use the following:

```
$ MYARRAY=($(cat primary_nodes.txt))
```

however **this should be avoided** for as file globbing and literal whitespaces can give unexpected results as Charles Duffy points out below

Comment: `arr=( $(...) )` is buggy by nature. If your `primary_nodes.txt` contains a `*`, this'll put a list of filenames in your current directory into the array. If you have a line with literal whitespace, it'll be split into multiple values. If it contains glob characters like `foo[bar]`, then it can become `fooa` or `foob` (or both of the above) depending on which filenames exist in the current directory.

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good call! Not expected, but _potentially_ quite useful ;-)